# Is temperature held fixed in this derivative for pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, definition

In Ashcroft and Mermin, they use the thermodynamic identity
$$P = -\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right)_N$$
to compute the pressure of an electron gas. Is temperature $T$ also held fixed here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, as discussed in Themis' answer, $-P$ is the partial derivative of the internal energy with respect to volume at fixed entropy. However, in the case of the electron gas in typical metals, we can justify the identification of pressure with the partial derivative of the internal energy with respect to volume at a fixed temperature.

The reason is due to the dependence of the thermal properties on the ratio $\frac{T}{T_F}$, where $T_F$ is the Fermi temperature of the order of $10^5$ K for typical metals. Therefore, room temperature properties do not differ significantly from zero temperature properties. Moreover, $TS$ is typically small as compared to the internal energy. Under such conditions,
$$
P=-\left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\right|_{T,N}= -\left.\frac{\partial (U-TS)}{\partial V}\right|_{T,N} \simeq
 -\left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right|_{T,N}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Begin with the fundamental equation
$$dU = T dS - P dV + \mu dN$$
which implies
$$
   T=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N},\quad
   -P=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N},\quad
   \mu=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial N}\right)_{S,V}
$$
Therefore, it is entropy that must be held constant in the equation in question. Perhaps Ashcroft and Mermin assume reversible process in closed adiabatic system ($S=\text{const}$ in this case).